# CSS not loading in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, loading

I have a problem on my site with non loading CSS files in IE.
The files are loaded fine in every other browser but in IE...if someone can help me with this...I'd be grateful. Site in question is:
http://www.colby.si/intro_slider/

Thanks again

Comment: That indeed helped...if you can post as an answer I can mark it as a solution then...thank you

Comment: did it solve your problem or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistype in the `type` attribute in both the css inclusion: so try writing `type='text/css'` instead of `type='textcss'`.

I suspect that the css file is requested and loaded by IE but not parsed due to the wrong mime-type. Also you may force the server to send the correct mime-type for file with `.css` extensions